# Understanding Difference between ToArray and JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, asp.net-4.0

I'm working on jquery to get data bind it to the dropdownlists & also I used web service method, and its working great but I'm not getting some clarification I,e for binding data to one dropdownlist I'm getting data from web method which is returns To Array objects and for another dropdownlist I'm getting data from web method which is returns in terms of JSON object, but in the front end I'm not getting any difference. most of them telling serialised json good method to work on, so what actually happens here? I'm bit confuse 
    please help me 
    thank you

```
**here is my code**
Default.aspx

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>JsonAndToArray</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            ddlActivityType = document.getElementById("<%=ddlActivity.ClientID %>");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset/utf-8",
                url: "Visit.asmx/GetActivityByJSON",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(results) {
                    results = eval(results.d);
                    $('#ddlActivity').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('#ddlActivity').get(0).options[0] = new Option('  --select--  ', '0');
                    $.each(results, function(val, text) {
                        $('#ddlActivity').append($('<option></option>').val(text[1]).html(text[0]));
                    });
                }
            });

            ddlActivityType1 = document.getElementById("<%=ddlActivity2.ClientID %>");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset/utf-8",
                url: "Visit.asmx/GetActivity",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(results) {
                    results = eval(results.d);
                    $('#ddlActivity2').get(0).options.length = 0;
                    $('#ddlActivity2').get(0).options[0] = new Option('--select--', '0');
                    $.each(results, function(val, text) {
                        $('#ddlActivity2').append($('<option></option>').val(text[1]).html(text[0]));
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    Json-Activity :
    <select id="ddlActivity" runat="server">
    </select>   
    <br />
    <br />
    ToArray-Activity :
    <select id="ddlActivity2" runat="server">
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnJson" runat="server" Text="Json" OnClick="Json_click"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>


Defalut.aspx.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public partial class Defalut: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Json_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}


**webservices**

**

 - Visit.asmx

**


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Facade;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Visit
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Visit : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    public Visit()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public IList<string[]> GetActivity()
    {
        IList<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();
        //string value = "";
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con_New = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog="Database";Integrated Security=True;");
            con_New.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdSelect_ST = new SqlCommand("select id,name from table", con_New);
            SqlDataAdapter da_ST = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSelect_ST);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da_ST.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] ActivityType = new string[2];
                ActivityType[0] = dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                ActivityType[1] = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
                values.Add(ActivityType);
            }          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return values;
    }


    [WebMethod]
    public string GetActivityByJSON()
    {
        IList<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();
        string value = "";
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con_New = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog="Database";Integrated Security=True;");
            con_New.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdSelect_ST = new SqlCommand("select name,id from table", con_New);
            SqlDataAdapter da_ST = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSelect_ST);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da_ST.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string[] ActivityType = new string[2];
                ActivityType[0] = dt.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
                ActivityType[1] = dt.Rows[i]["id"].ToString();
                values.Add(ActivityType);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            value = js.Serialize(values);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first call you are returning an array which is converted to a json array by the system. You return this:

```
IList<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();
```

---

In the second call you convert to a jsaon array and return it as a string.  Here is the code that does the conversion:

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
value = js.Serialize(values);
```

---

Since json is just a string formatted in a certain way -- there is no difference.  Just when the string to send back is created and who (your code or the system code) creates it.

Comment: then there is no essential need of doing json serialize and sending back to front end and we can use To Array in place of that, does it correct way I understood?

Comment: umm... sort of.  The system will do the json serialize for you.  The `ToArray()` is not in place of anything.

Comment: http://encosia.com/asmx-and-json-common-mistakes-and-misconceptions/,  I gone through this article and I cleared all my doughts thanku